# Having problems with convolution in Fourier space

Tags: convolution, fourier

First attempt:
I tried convolution in Fourier space.

1. step: transform grayscale image ==> (real1,imag1)
2. step: transform kernel (a simple box filter) ==> (real2, imag2)
3. step: multiply (complex) ==> 
   real=real1 · real2 - imag1 · imag2,  imag=real1 · imag2 + real2 · imag1
4. step: inverse FFT of (real,imag) result of multiply

The result is wrong (very very dark).

The FFT was performed following Bourke code at https://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/dft/

Second attempt:

1. step: transform a signal (120, 128, 148)
2. step: transform a kernel (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)
3. step: multiply (complex)
4. step: inverse FT of the result of multiply
   The result for the second value of the signal is 44 (rounded)

The result for space convolving is 132.

The second attempt was performed without FFT, sin and cos decomposition the second values was isolate

```
////////////////// this is the code (in Microsoft dll style) for the FFT 
///////////////// (dir=1 direct transform, dir=-1 inverse transform)
// In Place FFT
// nn=num points  m=exponent   nn=2^m
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) int __stdcall GB_FFT1D(int dir,int nn, 
                           int m,double *x,double *y)
{
    int Rtc=0;
 try{   

long i,i1,j,k,i2,l,l1,l2;
double c1,c2,tx,ty,t1,t2,u1,u2,z;

   // Do the bit reversal 
   i2 = nn >> 1;
   j = 0;
   for (i=0;i<nn-1;i++) {
      if (i < j) {
         tx = x[i];
         ty = y[i];
         x[i] = x[j];
         y[i] = y[j];
         x[j] = tx;
         y[j] = ty;
      }
      k = i2;
      while (k <= j) {
         j -= k;
         k >>= 1;
      }
      j += k;
   }

   // Compute the FFT 
   c1 = -1.0;
   c2 = 0.0;
   l2 = 1;
   for (l=0;l<m;l++) {
  l1 = l2;
  l2 <<= 1;
  u1 = 1.0;
  u2 = 0.0;
  for (j=0;j<l1;j++) {
     for (i=j;i<nn;i+=l2) {
            i1 = i + l1;
            t1 = u1 * x[i1] - u2 * y[i1];
            t2 = u1 * y[i1] + u2 * x[i1];
            x[i1] = x[i] - t1;
            y[i1] = y[i] - t2;
            x[i] += t1;
            y[i] += t2;
         }
         z =  u1 * c1 - u2 * c2;
         u2 = u1 * c2 + u2 * c1;
         u1 = z;
      }
      c2 = sqrt((1.0 - c1) / 2.0);
      if (dir == 1)
         c2 = -c2;
      c1 = sqrt((1.0 + c1) / 2.0);
   }

   // Scaling for forward transform 
   if (dir == 1) {
      for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
         x[i] /= (double)nn;
         y[i] /= (double)nn;
      }
   }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    return Rtc;
 }
 catch(...){ 
    Rtc=1;
    Return Rtc;
 }
}




/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  This is the 
dll entry for complex product

extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) int __stdcall 
GB_Prodotto_NumeriComplessi(double *real,double *imag,
                  double *real2,double *imag2,int w,int h)

{
    int Rtc=0;

 try{   

int x,y,i; 
double tmp;

i=0;
for (y=0;y<h;y++){
    for (x=0;x<w;x++){
    tmp=real[i]*real2[i]-imag[i]*imag2[i];
    imag[i]=real[i]*imag2[i]+imag[i]*real2[i];
    real[i]=tmp;
    i+=1;
}  // completato run x ==> first by in next row if any
}   
    return Rtc;
 }
 catch(...){ 
        Rtc=1;
        return Rtc;
 }
}
```

This is the Fourier transform code:

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) int __stdcall GB_FT_1D(int dir,
int N,double *x1,double *y1,double *x2,double *y2)

{
    int Rtc=0;

 try{   

   long i,k;
   double arg;
   double cosarg,sinarg;


   for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
      x2[i] = 0; y2[i] = 0;
      arg = - dir * 2.0 * 3.141592654 * (double)i / (double)N;
      for (k=0;k<N;k++) {
         cosarg = cos(k * arg);
         sinarg = sin(k * arg);
         x2[i] += (x1[k] * cosarg - y1[k] * sinarg);
         y2[i] += (x1[k] * sinarg + y1[k] * cosarg);
      }
   }

   /* Copy the data back */
   if (dir == 1) {
      for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
         x1[i] = x2[i] / (double)N;
         y1[i] = y2[i] / (double)N;
      }
   } else {
      for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
         x1[i] = x2[i];
         y1[i] = y2[i];
      }
   }


    return Rtc;
 }
 catch(...){ 
    Rtc=1;
    return Rtc;
 }
}
```

I hope the following will be more clear for my 1D process

```
1. Signal is allocated as N (N=3) elements double, with values: 120,128,148
2. Signal_real is allocated as N elements double and data are copied from Signal array
3. Signal_imag is allocated as N elements double with zero values
4. A couple of temporary arrays double (length=N) are allocated as x2,y2 for real and imag data
5. GB_FT_1D dll entry is invoked as:
   Rtc = GB_FT_1D(ByVal dir, ByVal N, ByVal x1Ptr, ByVal y1Ptr, ByVal x2Ptr, ByVal y2Ptr)
   where dir=1  direct transform
   x1Ptr=pointer to Signal_real array
   y1Ptr=pointer to Signal_imag array
   x2Ptr=pointer to x2 array
   y2Ptr=pointer to y2 array
The resulting data are in Signal_real,Signal_imag

For debugging:
 the same GB_FT_1D dll entry is invoked with dir=-1 (inverse Fourier transform)
 in Signal_real I get the original values (OK!)

Similar process is performed for Kernel with values: 1/3, 1/3, 1/13
Debugging is ok: inverse FT give the original Kernel values

After removing debugging, the product Signal X Kernel is performed as 
code for complex product 1D:

for (i=0:i<N:i++){ 
  real1 = Signal_real[i];
  imag1 = Signal_imag[i];
  real2 = Kernel_real[i];
  imag2 = Kernel_imag[i];
  Signal_real[i] = real1 * real2 - imag1 * imag2;
  Signal_imag[i] = real1 * imag2 + real2 * imag1;

}

GB_FT_1D dll entry is invoked with dir=-1 (now in Signal_real and 
    Signal_imag we have the product Signal X Kernel)

After inverse FT, in Signal_real I get: 44, 44, 44  wrong !!!

Convolving second element of Signal (value=128)  with kernel I get 132 
(the mean value) !!!
```

Comment: "very very dark" sounds exclusively like a visualization problem. And you forgot to transform back.

Comment: "The result for the second value of the signal is 44 (rounded)" that makes no sense, a convolution needs to yield a sequence, not a value.

Comment: Anyways, impossible to debug code we can't see.

Comment: Marcus, the inverse transform was performed.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to show where and how that was done! Your question doesn't mention it at all. Again, we still can't tell you what is wrong with your implementation if you don't *show* your implementation, and all we know about the result is "it's wrong". I'm afraid at this level of detail, your question is impossible to answer!

Comment: when  I use inverse FFT on transformed image  I get the original image.l

Comment: After complex product, I use inverse FFT.

Comment: The second attempt was performed without FFT, sin and cos decomposition the second values was isolate from the 3 output values. In the second attempt the inverse FT was performed after complex product too.

Comment: so, still no implementation code. Still impossible to help you then. Also, these numbers tell us nothing.

Comment: Please use the code formatting button! you seem to have added the code for the fft, and for a product. But not for the actual way you implement the convolution with these tools! So, we still don't know what you're doing and how it might be wrong.

Comment: I try to clearify my 1D process

Comment: so you're explaining *yet* another thing than simply sharing your 2D convolution's source code.

Comment: Marcus, I performed 2D convolution using FFT as the result is wrong I try  a very simple 1D convolution using FT not FFT (second attempt) but the result is wrong. My 2D convolution is more complex as I use Visualbasic and C++, the same is true for 1D , but 1D is simpler than 2D (in 2D FFT_1D is invoked by rows and then by colums). As I said inverse FFT (or FT) produces the expected data, but after complex product the inverse FFT (or inverse FT) produces wrong data.

Comment: So, OK; I think it's clear to me now that the question is actually about the 1D fast convolution. So, still: Your *text* sounds reasonable, but your results are wrong. What are we supposed to help you with then? We need to see the code. We can't help with your overall code being complex: as everywhere else, when you have a problem with your program code, and want outside help, you need to write a minimum example that does nothing but reproduce the problem, so you can give the code to someone else, they can run it, and tell you what's wrong. We still only have irrelevant parts of your code.